# Android - Is this possible? Different Intent based on what apps are installed

Tags: android, dictionary, android-intent

I have an app that uses maps. I want to give the user the choice to pick their own maps application, eg Google Maps, MapDroyd, OR give them the option to open in a **Browser**.
However, instead of going to `maps.google.com/....` or whatever the site is, I currently have it going to `mysite.com/find.php?lat=123.456&lon=456.789`.

So, I want a list of suitable apps to pop up and if they click the `browser` go to `mysite.com...`, if they click `Google Maps` launch an intent with `geo:123.456,567,890` and likewise if they have `MapDroyd` installed.

This will also depend on whether or not they have the apps installed in the first place! I suppose the easiest way is to just use the `geo:` intent but then the browser URL will be Googles URL and not my own!

So, is it possible to alter the default Google Maps URL when the browser is selected?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is it possible to alter the default Google Maps URL when the browser is selected?

No.

> So, I want a list of suitable apps to pop up

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` for each distinct `Intent` you would want to use. Combine the results (use a `HashSet` or otherwise net out anything that responds to both `Intents`). Display the results in a dialog.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) demonstrates using `queryIntentActivities()` and launching activities based on a chosen result. It does not handle your multiple possible `Intents` nor uses a dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll take a look at that source now. I guess what I'm really trying to do is create a popup dialog with browser, google maps, and mapDroyd, assuming all are installed, and then have click listeners for each, then depending on each, just launch a seperate intent. The hard part is building the dialog itself with the custom apps.